# What is the best practice for database scalability

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

Note: I am completely new to storing and accessing online DBs. I have, hover, taught myself enough about asp.net / SQL, html and JS to create a web app. Currently I have a web app hosted on a Godaddy account, which includes one SQL Server, which I am using for log-in validation (it supports asp account wizard--that is why I used it). I know that my app will fill up that database fairly quickly (it is 1 gig limit), so I hoped to use the 10 included MySql databases that come wit the Godaddy account in combination with the SQL server. My question is: can I use the SQL server for handling the accounts and authentication, and then store the user data in the MySql DBs? Or am I completely out to lunch with my thinking? I want to set this up right the first time so that I can safely scale up.
Or, should I forget Godaddy completely and try MS Azure?
Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would use MongoDB, because it is web scale ; )

Comment: So is MySQL.  MongoDB and MySQL solve different classes of storage problems, and each has a solid role in any modern stack.

Comment: And many many high activity sites also use SQL Server. I know people who mange Ql Server instnces with trilllions of rows, so wenb scale is a fallacy. Yes badly designed databases don;t scale well, yes it takes expertise to scale reational datbases, but then I woudln;t trust my trillion records to someone who wasn't an expert personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about best practices for scaling up.

One best practice is to avoid the need for multiple parallel technologies (e.g. SQL Server and MySQL).  That's because web apps that use a single tech are easier to migrate to more capable hosting platforms. If you enjoy any success you *will* need to move away from Go Daddy hosting.

Another best practice is to make your database access layer as simple and as vendor-neutral as you possibly can. Try to avoid vendor-specific features where possible. This gives you the power to switch vendors at reasonable cost. Commercial database and infrastructure vendors rely for their profits on their ability to lock in customers when the customers succeed and need to scale up fast.

A third best practice is to avoid mixing database-connection and application logic.

Comment: I liked all the answers, but picked this one because it solidified my thoughts that I would like to stay with SQL Server (partly because I feel comfortable with it and it does everything I need) and, as you said "avoid having two technologies". I think I was really trying to figure out if I needed to investigate another host--which I believe I will.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely do that.  It is fairly common (though usually not for that reason) for a single application to use multiple data sources.

If you are using Entity Framework, check out the MySQL documentation for setting that up in your .NET application

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

Keep in mind that you will have the complexity of managing two different databases (backup / restore / maintenance).

Comment: Not sure if I used Entity (sorry for my ignorance on the topic--I used a MS Visual Studio .net template with a signup wizard, set up the DB as a asp schema--not sure if that is the right terms). I will check out the link in relation to my existing DB set up.

Comment: @Cory You probably didn't use Entity then. But the principle still holds, multiple databases can be used by one app.

Comment: @Cory: For whatever you plan to store in the MySQL database, I would suggest that you learn and use Entity Framework.  It is *way* more productive than doing things with ADO.Net.

Comment: Both very useful comments!